# Open only the first 10 lines of large CSV file in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: linux, bash, csv, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I will start receiving many large CSV files, of which only the first few lines are of interest to me. I was hoping to open them by piping only the first few lines to Calc, but this *doesn't work*:

```
$ libreoffice4.1 --calc <(head large_file.csv)
```

Upon trying this, I get a popup:

> /dev/fd/63 does not exist.

Is there any easy way to open only the first few lines without creating a new (temporary) file? This is on Kubuntu Linux 12.10 with LibreOffice 4.1.

Comment: Does it _need_ to be in libreoffice? I mean, a simple `cat` or `less` won't do?

Comment: I prefer Calc as the lines are _long_ (over 30 columns) and are of arbitrary length. I (human) need to read real data out of them.

Comment: Does [this q/a](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91088/9558) solve your issue?

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Yes, it does set me in the right direction to answer the question. You can link to that post or paraphrase it as an answer, and I'll accept. Thank you tohuwawohu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using an unnamed pipe, why not use a named pipe. For example:

```
% mknod p pipe
% (head large_file.csv > pipe &); libreoffice4.1 --calc pipe
```

Comment: Thank you, beautiful solution! It is a rarity when a knowledgeable answer is posted over a year after the question!